In Genymotion, a couple of apps are not visible in Play store. Reason?
In Genymotion, a couple of apps, for example, Brawl Stars are not available in the Google Play Store on any of the OS I tried.
Why is this? and how do I sort it out? Any workarounds?

Possibly related/dupe: Why the game is compatible in BlueStacks, but not in Genymotion?

@AndrewT. Yes, it surely seems like a duplicate :), srorry i did not notice. I think the question is duplicate but this current answer adds something extra

Genymotion in VirtualBox based emulator which means it can not emulate a different architecture of the host CPU. If your PC has an Intel/ADM x86_64 CPU then the virtual Android device will also run with that architecture.
But next to all Android device have arm/arm64 CPU architecture. For running apps that have no code for x86 or x86_64 architecture some Genymotion emulator images contain a translation engine that is capable of translating arm-v7 (Arm 32bit) code to x86/x86_64 code. However this translation engine is AFAIR not available in all emulator images.
Without that translation engine you will only see apps that are capable of running on x86 or x86_64.
Some games only support arm64-v8a (Arm 64 bit) as CPU architecture. Those apps are the one Genymotion can not execute at all even if the emulator image contains the translation system.
See also Genymotion support page on that topic.

Thanks! A lot appreciate it (+1). Just a little help, how do i get a translation engine (after doing research, i still couldn't find it), can you just guide me regarding shifting to arm through translation engine because it's my first time, also can we change the architecture manually?

Im stuck at a point where i downloaded the translation tool zip but am unable to run it and install it in the system. Appreciate any help

@Arjun I don't think that the answer Andrew posted the link to is still applicable. It was written for the Genymotion emulator version from 2017. A more recent version that also supports arm64 seems to be this project: https://github.com/niizam/Genymotion_A11_libhoudini

Thanks a lot @Robert, I appreciate it
